# Simplest way to reduce string into letters, numbers, and spaces without regex in Swift?

Tags: swift

I currently have a function whose purpose is to remove all characters that aren't letters, numbers, or spaces from strings. But frankly, I'm sick of regex, because it's an ugly dinosaur. I want a Swiftier way to handle this function. Is there one?

```
func cleanName(_ name: String) -> String {
    let negated = "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+"
    return name.replacingOccurrences(of: negated, with: "", options: [.regularExpression])
}

let name = "@$%ab_049*"
print(cleanName(name)) // ab049
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Swift 5 or latter Character properties like `isLetter`, `isWholeNumber` and `isWhitespace` combined and filter the valid characters:

```
func cleanName(_ name: String) -> String {
    name.filter{ $0.isLetter || $0.isWholeNumber || $0.isWhitespace }
}
```

---

Another option is to use pattern matching operator:

```
func cleanName(_ name: String) -> String {
    name.filter{ "0"..."9" ~= $0 || "A"..."Z" ~= $0 || "a"..."z" ~= $0 || $0 == " " } 
}
```

---

> Note: Beware that `isLetter` is not equivalent to [A-Za-z]. It will return true for some special characters as well as the regular alphabet. From the docs the following characters are all letters:
> • “A” (U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A)
> • “é” (U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E, U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)
> • “ϴ” (U+03F4 GREEK CAPITAL THETA SYMBOL)
> • “ڈ” (U+0688 ARABIC LETTER DDAL)
> • “日” (U+65E5 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-65E5)
> • “ᚨ” (U+16A8 RUNIC LETTER ANSUZ A)

---

> The same applies for `isWholeNumber` character property. From the docs the following characters all represent whole numbers:
> • “1” (U+0031 DIGIT ONE) => 1
> • “५” (U+096B DEVANAGARI DIGIT FIVE) => 5
> • “๙” (U+0E59 THAI DIGIT NINE) => 9
> • “万” (U+4E07 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4E07) => 10_000

---

So if you want to get the same behavior of the regex on your post you can extend Character and create your own computed property to return true only for characters from a-z, A-Z or 0-9:

```
extension Character {
    var isAlphabet: Bool { "a"..."z" ~= self || "A"..."Z" ~= self }
    var isDigit: Bool { "0"..."9" ~= self }
    var isAlphaNumeric: Bool { isAlphabet || isDigit }
    var isAlphaNumericOrSpace: Bool { isAlphabet || isDigit || self == " " }
}
```

---

You can also extend StringProtocol and create a custom property to clean up your string:

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var cleanedUp: Self {
        filter(\.isAlphaNumericOrSpace)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let name = "@$%ab_049*"
name.cleanedUp  // ab049
```

Comment: That first one is so Swifty tho.